# Flutter selection page transformer

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to make a widget like this, I am a beginner - how can I make this?
There is one additional constraint: the selection bar above can have more than 3 options.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will help to you make swiper page design

Flutter dependency : [flutter_swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)

https://github.com/lohanidamodar/flutter_ui_challenges/blob/master/lib/src/pages/animations/animation1/animation1.dart

[image]

Comment: Instead of an image, I need to have text rows in the body.
Let me try if replacing with a text widget works!